# Tidyr's crossing() function not producing expected names in output

Tags: r, tidyr

I apologize in advance that I could not create a reproducible example, but when I do `tidyr::crossing` on some dataframes, I get a crossed tibble where the `x` variables have the form: `x$col_name` and the `y` variables have  `y$col_name`. If I do:

```
crossing(iris,mtcars)
```

I get names that don't have the `x$` prefix, as desired. I checked that the class of the input dataframes are the same as the example above, and there are no duplicate names in the example I'm working with. I can't share the data for the usual privacy reasons. I realize there is not much to work with here, but I'm hoping someone here is experience enough with `tidyr` to understand this issue.

Here is some session info:

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] writexl_1.4.0   readxl_1.4.0    lubridate_1.8.0 forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.9    
 [7] purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.2.0     tibble_3.1.7    ggplot2_3.3.6   tidyverse_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.7.0     compiler_4.2.0   dbplyr_2.2.0     tools_4.2.0     
 [6] jsonlite_1.8.0   lifecycle_1.0.1  gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.2     
[11] reprex_2.0.1     rstudioapi_0.13  DBI_1.1.3        cli_3.3.0        haven_2.5.0     
[16] xml2_1.3.3       withr_2.5.0      httr_1.4.3       fs_1.5.2         generics_0.1.2  
[21] vctrs_0.4.1      hms_1.1.1        grid_4.2.0       tidyselect_1.1.2 glue_1.6.2      
[26] R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.3      tzdb_0.3.0       modelr_0.1.8     magrittr_2.0.3  
[31] backports_1.4.1  scales_1.2.0     ellipsis_0.3.2   rvest_1.0.2      assertthat_0.2.1
[36] colorspace_2.0-3 utf8_1.2.2       stringi_1.7.6    munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.8.0     
[41] crayon_1.5.1
```

Comment: Do you have column names common in those datasets.  Please check the `str` of those datasets.

Comment: column names are different. Let me know what else I can investigate...thanks.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can check the `str` of those datasets giving unusual results compared to the ones that give correct one.  There must be something going on it those.  If you can show the `str` output edited here, it may help others

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the answer is simple:

```
crossing(iris,mtcars)
```

```
crossing(x = iris,y = mtcars)
```

This is rather odd behavior in my opinion.